# Invalid initial heap size: -Xms5g

Tags: java, batch-file, heap-size

I try to open the software Cyc on windows (available here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencyc/files/OpenCyc%204.0/).

I follow the instructions and execute the BAT file "run-cyc" to start, then I have this message on the cmd.exe:

```
PORT OFFSET = 00
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms5g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
...
```

I know I have to change the size using a command like "java -Xms200m" (which size would be the best?) but I don't know what to write exactly.

Here is the script of the BAT file:

```
rem run-cyc.bat
rem
rem
rem Assumes that java 1.5 or higher (1.6 or higher preferably) is in your path

set CLASSPATH=lib\cyc.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\subl.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\junit.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\cycSparqlEndpoint.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;resource
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\ext\
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;plugins\
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\ant-1.6.5.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-security-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-xml-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\ecj-3.5.1.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-server-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-continuation-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-servlet-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-http-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-util-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-io-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\jetty-webapp-8.0.4.v20111024.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;lib\servlet-api-3.0.20100224.jar

set "BACKGROUND="

if "%1"=="-b" (
set "BACKGROUND=-b "
SHIFT
)
rem Use DEFAULT_PORT_OFFSET unless another offset was passed as the last 
rem argument this bat file

set DEFAULT_PORT_OFFSET=00

if "%1"==""  (
SET PORT_OFFSET=%DEFAULT_PORT_OFFSET%
goto :port_set
)

if  "%1"=="00" goto :set_port
if  "%1"=="20" goto :set_port
if  "%1"=="40" goto :set_port
if  "%1"=="60" goto :set_port
if  "%1"=="80" goto :set_port

rem AN INVALID PORT WAS SPECIFIED
echo ....ERROR Invalid port offset specified: %1%
if not defined BACKGROUND pause
exit

:set_port
SET PORT_OFFSET=%1

:port_set
echo PORT_OFFSET = %PORT_OFFSET%

set INIT_FORM="(progn (load \"init/jrtl-release-init.lisp\") (cinc *base-tcp-port* %PORT_OFFSET%) (load \"init/port-init.lisp\"))"

rem Add the following line to the JVM options to allow remote debugging
rem -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8888,suspend=n

java -server -Xms5g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:-UseSpinning -XX:PreBlockSpin=10 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp %CLASSPATH% com.cyc.tool.subl.jrtl.nativeCode.subLisp.SubLMain %BACKGROUND% -f %INIT_FORM%

if not defined BACKGROUND pause
```

So can you tell me how to change the size, and where? With a command in cmd.exe or inside the BAT file ?

Thank you

Comment: 5 Gb is too big if you're running 32-bit version of Java. You also have to set `-Xmx5g` (max size) when you set `-Xms5g` (min size).

Comment: Thank you but what command line do I have to write to make those changes?

Comment: @RomainCharles If you [edit] and include the bat file in the question you might get an answer.

Comment: Thank you that's what I did just now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-Xms5g` which seems too big for your machine, and start smaller, perhaps your mentioned `-Xms200m` would be a ok starting point.

Comment: Thank you but how do I do that? How do I set the min and max size with this program? What command line do I have to write?

Comment: My guess would be that java is called in the .bat script.

Comment: @RomainCharles If you [edit] and include the bat file in the question you might get an answer.

Comment: In the .bat script you now added you can remove/replace `-Xms5g -Xmx8g` (close to the bottom) to your liking, and run again.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need a 64 bit OS and a 64-bit Java install.  The release notes for OpenCyc state:

Note the release notes (that you linked to!) state:

```
OpenCyc requires 3G RAM under 64bit and about 1G of disk space.
Running OpenCyc under 32bit is no longer supported.
```

So, while the suggested change to the BAT file *might* work, it is unlikely that running Cyc with half<sup>1</sup> the *minimum* recommended heap size is going to to be pleasant.

---

<sup>1 - The maximum Java heap size that you can expect to work on a 32 bit Windows platform is 1.5 to 1.8 GB ... for reasons due to the architecture of Windows.</sup>